# How to reduce the rate of packet using the RTP in Java with jlibrtp

Tags: java, packet, rtp

I am just using the RTP to send some bufferedimage from the client to the server using the jlibrtp.

And each packet is limited to 1480bytes so I need to divide each image to several parts and send the byte to the server and at the server side it need to wait, until it receives all the bytes and reform a bufferedimage.

But the problem is very often when the bufferedimage size is too large some of the packets will loss. However, when I try to reduce the size, this problem does not happen.

Actually the image I send is the continuous frame capture from the webcam, so when I try to drop those "not complete" image, the image screen shows in a very "non-continuously" way which is not acceptable.

So I would like to ask is there any ways to improve this situation?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What codec do you use to encode the frame?

Comment: i just grab the image from the webcam using javaCV and convert the image to byte array and send it

Comment: Why don't you feed the data on a MPEG stream and send this stream over the network (look for JMF / FMJ libraries for this). MPEG offers some resilience on the network and is able to deal with frame loss.

Answer (score 0):

- Switch to a video encoding format like MPEG-2, MPEG-4, Theora or WebM.
- You can send back to the sender that you didn't get some packets and need them resent. The advantage here over TCP is that you can easily time out and stop asking when the packet is too old. I cannot find it quickly for jlibrtp but other RTP libraries have a retransmit request function.
- You can reduce the image resolution and send less data.
- You can start sending more data. If this extra data is part of a [forward error correction system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction) you may be able to reconstruct the lost packets.
- You can do both, reducing the resolution and increasing the error correction so the bandwidth remains similar.